# SQL Server 2012 Bulk Import From Excel

Tags: sql, import, sql-server-2012, varbinary

I have a very simple question: my client has an Excel worksheet containing 700+ records. One of the column in the worksheet has passwords stored in plain text format.

In my SQL Server 2012 database, I have a table called `tbusers` with the same no. of columns as the Excel worksheet & in the same sequence.

However I have the password column as `varbinary(max)` because I store the passwords in encrypted format by creating an asymmetric key with des-512 algo.

When I try to import the Excel using the wizard into the table the password column comes as null despite being converted it shows null.

Kindly help me on this.. how to convert the password field of excel worksheet into varbinary before it's imported into the table using either wizard or T-SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the excel data to a staging table.  Do what you need to do with the data, including encrypting the password.  Write to the tbusers table from the staging table.

Comment: My client will give me many worksheets in future and the same process has to continue. Can you pls elaborate on staging tables.

Comment: It's also called a working table.  It's a table in your database that does not necessarily relate to any other tables.  It's purpose is to perform the "T" of "ETL".  ETL stands for Extraction, Transformation, Load.  It's a way of populating database tables from external sources.

Comment: Thanks Dan an example would help